# How to decompose workflow's node classes DDD-way?

Tags: object-oriented, domain-driven-design, modeling

System model has Workflow container class, instances of which may contain subclasses of the Node class, specialized for different behaviors (eg, Initial, Intermediate1, Intermediate2, Final). There are other classes Node classes use as a context, eg, User and Content (which can have Workflows of different kinds), but they are not an issue here.

However, each Node subclass has different "areas" of behavior: basic metadata (like Name and parameters), state transition logic support (eg, condition for node availability, etc), messaging support for multiple languages and channels (this is the core of the business case), rules for possible further actions for the node. (And I have not touched more ubiquitous aspects like access rights management here - just to say the list of aspects is not carved in stone.) For now, workflow is mostly a sequence of nodes, but there are some exceptions in transitions. So container is modeled as list of nodes and nodes are addressed by their ids.

Most direct approach, eg, splitting each Node subclass into NodeData, NodeTransition, NodeMessaging, NodeAction kind of miss the point and introduces necessity to keep closely related entities synchronized (eg, NodeMessaging needs name from NodeData, possible actions from NodeAction, etc, etc, so this kind of decomposition feels unnatural and thusly modeled entities are inconvenient.

The use of the classes is mostly rendering views and messages for different channels, having some stats on Content wrt current "Node" it uses, and of course for Workflow it is changing from one "Node" to another. Maybe I have not mentioned some minor cases, but as I see it, only Workflow and Nodes are entities, and other things have very limited behaviors, so perhaps can be modeled as value objects...

What could be good pattern here? I guess, implementations of workflows may have some good pattern to adjust to the system in question needs. I am only aware of one implementation, which heavily leverages Component Architecture, and I it's overkill for the case, and also I do not think it's elegant enough.

And as mentioned in the title, I prefer solutions, which are nearer domain-driven design. The application domain does not provide enough details to even name anything beyond Node subclasses, so some adequate (in sense of complexity) solution domain patter could be nice. In DDD-speak, it's about aggregating right.

Comment: Why do you have a workflow container class? is it part of the domain or it is infrastructure related ? (something related to relational db)
The main idea about DDD is to separate the domain so if your domain doesn't have a workflow container you shouldn't have a workflow container class. The model can be System that has many Nodes. The problem of persisting the model can be solved later.

Comment: In this case, container has a definite place in the domain, and, yes, you guessed right, it also provides persistence for it's nodes' data. Nodes do not have any meaning without being part of the container, and there could be many containers with different nodes.